# Iterating over a flexible range in ERB

Tags: ruby, puppet, erb

I've got a Puppet ERB template on version 3.8.1 which is throwing an error and refusing to work.

Here's my original code:

```
<%= (1..5).select{ |i| "elastic%d" %[i] != @hostname }.map{|x, i| "elastic%d" %[x]} %>
```

This creates an array of host names excluding the current host's hostname.

I'm trying to parameterize my template so it can scale things nicely depending on the amount of servers I have in my cluster:

```
<%= (1..@(scope.lookupvar('mymodule::elastic_instances'))).select{ |i| "elastic%d" %[i] != @hostname }.map{|x, i| "elastic%d" %[x]} %>
```

This throws the following exception:

```
Error: Could not run: /home/tk/puppet/modules/mymodule/templates/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template.conf.erb:329: `@(' is not allowed as an instance variable name
/home/tk/puppet/modules/mymodule/templates/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template.conf.erb:329: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
; _erbout.concat(( (1..@(scope.lookupvar('mymodule...
```

I've also tried the following alternatives:

```
<%= (1..@(scope.lookupvar('mymodule::elastic_instances'))).select{ |i| "elastic%d" %[i] != @hostname }.map{|x, i| "elastic%d" %[x]} %>
<%= (1..(scope.lookupvar('mymodule::elastic_instances'))).select{ |i| "elastic%d" %[i] != @hostname }.map{|x, i| "elastic%d" %[x]} %>
<%= (1..scope.lookupvar('mymodule::elastic_instances')).select{ |i| "elastic%d" %[i] != @hostname }.map{|x, i| "elastic%d" %[x]} %>
```

Is there a manual method I can call which will work in place of Ruby's syntactic sugar?

Comment: Can you share what value `scope.lookupvar('mymodule::elastic_instances')` returns? Perhaps [`pry`](https://github.com/pry/pry) is your friend here if you wanted to use it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the variable as being returned by Puppet was a string rather than an int, though I declared it as an int in Puppet.

With a cast and some manual stuff, I got it working:

```
<%= (Range.new(1, Integer(scope.lookupvar('mymodule::elastic_instances'))) ... %>
```

That got things working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PuppetDB, you might want to take a look at the [puppetdb-query module](https://github.com/dalen/puppet-puppetdbquery).

Using that, you could retrieve a list of host names from the DB, so that the template can just iterate them like

```
<% @elastic_search_hostnames.each do -%>
...
<% end -%>
```